# Django Pagination Error. Which object to use as page_obj?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am trying to make a quiz where each question will be displayed on a different page. But I guess attributes like has_previous and has_next are not working.

**views.py**

```
def instructions(request):
  ques = Questionm.objects.first()
  context = {'ques': ques}
  return render(request,'events/instructions.html', context)
def ques_detail(request,pk=Questionm.objects.filter(marks=10).order_by("pk").values().first()):
  ques = get_object_or_404(Questionm, pk=pk)
  context = {'ques': ques}
  paginate_by = 1
  return render(request, 'events/ques_detail.html', context)
def ques_detail2(request, pk):
  ques = get_object_or_404(Questioni, pk=pk)
  context = {'ques': ques}
  paginate_by = 1
  return render(request, 'events/ques_detail2.html', context)
```

**ques_detail.html**

```
{% block title %}
<div class="round1">
 <h1>ROUND-1</h1>
</div>
<div class="ques">
  <h2>Q. {{ ques.question }}</h2><br><br><br><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="opt1">{{ ques.opt1 }}<br><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="opt2">{{ ques.opt2 }}<br><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="opt3">{{ ques.opt3 }}<br><br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="opt4">{{ ques.opt4 }}<br><br></p>
  <div class="pagination">
        {% if is_paginated %}
            {% if ques.has_previous %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ ques.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% for num in ques.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if ques.number == num %}
                    <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if ques.has_next %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ ques.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
   </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

I am just able to see question and four options. Not the previous and next buttons.
Someone kindly help.

Comment: You're not doing any pagination here at all. Why would you expect the Question object to have any of those attributes?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Can you please tell me the code to be added for pagination?

Comment: Well [the pagination docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/) are comprehensive. But you don't actually want pagination here. Pagination is for lists; you have a single item each time. It's not even clear what "next" and "previous" would refer to in this case. (And that video appears to be about hair products.)